# How do I get environment variables to persist into an imported Docker image

Tags: docker

I create a Dockerfile with the following:

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV test this
```

I build the image in the current directory:

```
docker build -t="test" .
```

I run this image, just to confirm that my environment variable is set:

```
docker run -t -i <image id> /bin/bash
```

I type `set` within the running container, and confirm that `test=this`.

After exiting the container, I export the image with the following two commands:

```
cont=`docker run -d <image id> ls`
docker export $cont > test.tar
```

I then import the image via:

```
cat test.tar | docker import - imported
```

Run the new image:

```
docker run -t -i <image id returned from prev cmd> /bin/bash
```

I type `set` within this running container, and my environment variable no longer exists

**What am I doing wrong?**

*I've done this with images with other commands in, and everything but the environment variables seem to persist.*

Comment: Have you considered to save the image instead of exporting the container?

Comment: "Save the image"?  Is there a way to do that?  `docker export` only takes container ids

Comment: Yes, you can save an image: `docker save your/image > /home/you/some-file.tar`. To get the image back you need to load it (instead of importing it). I wrote a blog post about this a couple of weeks ago: http://tuhrig.de/difference-between-save-and-export-in-docker/

Comment: @Thomas: Yes!  the `save`/`load` keeps my env vars. I didn't even know this existed.  Please create an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could save the image instead of export the container:

```
docker save your/image > /home/you/some-file.tar
```

If you use `save`, you need to use `load` to restore the image:

```
docker load < /home/you/some-file.tar
```

I wrote a blog post about the difference of `export` and `save` a couple of weeks ago: http://tuhrig.de/difference-between-save-and-export-in-docker/